# Create a graph with a Midi File

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, midi

I need to create a Graph of wave from a midi file but not able to do so, previously with a mp3 file using `AVAssetReader`, I am able to create the graph but with Midi file `AVAssetReader` is failed to read that file, so I am not able to get the information for creating the graph.

So my question is How to create a Graph from a Midi File.

The graph should be something like this -

[image]

Looking for some help.

Comment: Midi files do not have any samples to graph. Maybe you could try rendering your MIDI first (separate, possibly involved topic) and then graph the rendering's samples.

Comment: @Brandin You mean to say the information of graph should be in the Midi File ?

Comment: MIDI is a standard defining instructions telling the synth what to play and how to play it. MIDI files hold no audio data.

Comment: Convert the MIDI to wave first if possible, then graph it.